# Slider makes my app crashes ios

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, slider

I was trying to implement a slider in my app, I put a slider on the storyboard and when I run the app and try to slide it app crashes with the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7a28ff8)
```

I searched on the web and this error is related to a function called infinite times without exiting from its calling loop. The problem is that I haven't even connected my slider to code, so it doesn't call any function!
So, what's wrong with this damn slider?

EDIT: here is a screen
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQo9s.png)

Comment: provide the code you wrote for a slider, and add the screenshot of that slider if possible so another can understands your problem correctly.

Comment: @PriyankaPatil I'va added a screenshot, but I haven't wrote any code for the slider, only put it in the layout

Comment: can you show the code written for it? It may help me in understanding and solve the issue.

Comment: @PriyankaPatil I haven't written any code for it, only put the slider into layout. It's not connected to code

Answer (score 0):

Create an outlet for slider object,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider * slider;
```

then give an action

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    // write the code that you want to perform after moving the slider
}
```

try this code

Comment: so, the issue is not with the slider. The issue with other parts of a code.